# pip install 2 packages from requirements one after the other

Tags: python, pip, fasttext

I want to install `fasttext` using pip. But fasttext needs `Cython`. The error can be seen here:

```
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:    
Traceback (most recent call last):      
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>      
  File "/tmp/pip-install-3if14395/fasttext/setup.py", line 3, in <module>        
    from Cython.Build import cythonize    
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cython'
```

To solve this from the command line, I would do:

```
pip install Cython
pip install fasttext
```

and it would work.

But here, I need to install my packages from a single `requirements.txt` file like this: `pip install -r requirements.txt`.

If my `requirements.txt` file looks like this:

```
Cython
fasttext
```

It still gives me the error that `fasttext` needs `Cython` to be installed.

Is there a way, all in a single `requirements.txt` file, to ask `pip` to wait until `Cython` is installed to launch the `fasttext` install?

Comment: You can do a bash script which installs line by line from requirements.txt. This was your dependencies wont cause a problem

Comment: @Bayko It's a good idea, but here, I can't do that. The reason is that the install is being made via a platform and I do not have access to the terminal. (Or to be more precise, I do, but it's not advised to touch the python environments from the command line in my case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to install `fasttext` try adding the following to your requirements.txt:

```
numpy
scipy
pybind11
git+https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText.git
```

Comment: This works, it solves my problem! But I'm still curious to know if it's possible to tell `pip` to wait for another install to complete before beginning another one.